# How to use Athena with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdo, prepared-statement, amazon-athena

We're looking to have a specific search/aggregate/graphs page use AWS Athena instead of Postgres.

We've tried 2 ODBC packages for laravel, and discovered that Laravel uses prepared statements and Athena's Simba ODBC driver does not support prepared statements. PDO supports emulating prepared statements, which sounds like exactly what would work, but enabling ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES doesn't make any difference.

This is the error we're getting:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 0 [Simba][Athena] (1040) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. Athena Error No: 102, HTTP Response Code: 1, Error Message: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:1: Incorrect number of parameters: expected 1 but found 0 [Execution ID: ] (SQLPrepare[0] at /build/php7.2-PL0pac/php7.2-7.2.16/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_driver.c:206) (SQL: select * from "qa_lines_csv" where "id" > 100 limit 1)'

Our database config:

```php
        'test_athena' => [
            'driver' => 'odbc',
            'dsn' => 'odbc:Driver=/opt/simba/athenaodbc/lib/64/libathenaodbc_sb64.so;'
                    .'AwsRegion=us-east-1;'
                    .'AuthenticationType=IAM Credentials;'
                    .'UID=<redacted>;'
                    .'PWD=<redacted>;'
                    .'S3OutputLocation=s3://<redacted>/;',
            'host' => env('ATHENA_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('ATHENA_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('ATHENA_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('ATHENA_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('ATHENA_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'options' => [
                \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
            ],
```

```php
$pdo = DB::connection('test_athena')->getPdo();

// this crashes
$pdo->prepare('select * from "qa_lines_csv" where "id" > ? limit 1')->execute([100]);

// this does not crash
$pdo->prepare('select * from "qa_lines_csv" where "id" > 100 limit 1')->execute([]);

// this crashes
DB::connection('test_athena')->table('qa_lines_csv')->where('id', '>', 100)->first()
```

It seems like there is a bug between PDO and the Simba driver, one of them is not allowing the PDO emulation to work. Athena should just start supporting prepared statements.

We've already written our application, so we can't re-write everything to not use Laravel's query builder and manually concatenate strings into queries.

Comment: You probably know that Athena is based on Presto. However, they have different frontend and so, different drivers. If this is an option for you, I would suggest checking if Presto + Presto drivers solve the problem.

Comment: Hey Michola, I also need to connect Athena from my laravel app. Did you ever figure out the issue with pdo?

Comment: It works fine if your query string is ready to go without parametrization (aka no `?` or `:namedvar`). I considered Athena a dead-end and moved on.